# Is it possible to select pseudo elements like scrollbars using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, pseudo-element

Is it possible to select pseudo elements like these:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar
::-webkit-scrollbar-track
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
```

through jQuery?

```css
#scroller {
  background: #fff;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scroller">
  <p>
    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. 
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Scrollbars aren't *web* elements - they're *browser* elements.

Comment: What is it you want to do exactly, Why do you need them?

Comment: I would guess this question is predicated on a false assumption, and thus is not answerable in its current form. I suggest editing the question with more detail.

Comment: In general, JavaScript can't access pseudo-elements that are prefixed with `::`. They're only meaningful in CSS, to let you style those elements.

Comment: jQuery cannot "directly" access pseudo elements, but you can add a class to an element with a pseudo element to change that pseudo element. However, this will not be useful in your case.

Answer (score 2):

You can "read" the values of the pseudo elements, however you cannot change them, or so I have found.

Trying to set the property value returns the error:

> Failed to execute 'setProperty' on 'CSSStyleDeclaration': These styles are computed, and therefore the 'width' property is read-only.

```js
var width = window.getComputedStyle(
  document.querySelector('#scroller'), '::-webkit-scrollbar').getPropertyValue('width');

console.log('::-webkit-scrollbar width> ' + width);

$(document).on('click', function() {
  // window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.element'), '::-webkit-scrollbar').setProperty('width', '8px');
  // returns "Failed to execute 'setProperty' on 'CSSStyleDeclaration': These styles are computed, and therefore the 'width' property is read-only."
});
```

```css
#scroller {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: #eee;
}

#scroller::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px !important;
}


/* Track */
#scroller::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #eee !important;
}


/* Handle */
#scroller::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #555 !important;
}


/* Handle on hover */
#scroller::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #777 !important;
}

#scroller p {
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scroller">
  <p>
  </p>
</div>
```